# Make boxes of the same width

Tags: graph, graphviz

I'm trying to make a flowchart. In this flowchart, I want to have boxed nodes with varying labels (and thus varying label sizes), but I want the nodes to have the same size.

The source code is the following:

```
digraph G {

    a0 [ label="this is a loooong label" ]
    a3 [ label="short label" ]

    b0 [ label="this is a long label" ]
    b3 [ label="short label" ]

    a0, a1, a2, a3 [ shape=box ]
    b0, b1, b2, b3 [ shape=box ]

    subgraph cluster_one {
        style=filled;
        color=lightgrey;

        a0 -> a1 -> a2 -> a3;

        label = "This is nice and grey";
    }

    subgraph cluster_two {
        b0 -> b1 -> b2 -> b3;
        label = "This is nice and white";
        color=blue;
    }

}
```

I get this image:

[image: Flowchart]

I want the boxes in the subgraphs to have the same width. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set default values for nodes via `node [width=5]`. this sets the minimum size. If you set `fixed-size=true` this will be the actual size.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global node style, like this:

```
digraph G {

  node[width=4]
  ...
```